# Side effects of knitr when using a verbatim code chunk in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Adding a verbatim code junk I used the code snippet from https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/. The verbatim code is displayed correctly but as a side effect the following code chunks do not have the RStudio program controls ("Modify Chunk Options", "Run All Chunks Above" and "Run Current Chunk"). The commands for the whole file e.g. "Knit Document" and "Run All" work. But "Run selected Line(s)" produces an error `Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name` and "Run Current Chunk" does nothing.

I added a screenshot so that the detailed code of the verbatim code chunk is visible. Did I something wrong or do I have to live with these side effects?

[image: Side effects of knitr when using a verbatim code chunk in RStudio]

```r
xfun::session_info()
#> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
#> 
#> Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> Package version:
#>   base64enc_0.1.3 compiler_3.6.1  digest_0.6.20   evaluate_0.14  
#>   glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.6.1  grDevices_3.6.1 highr_0.8      
#>   htmltools_0.3.6 jsonlite_1.6    knitr_1.25      magrittr_1.5   
#>   markdown_1.1    methods_3.6.1   mime_0.7        Rcpp_1.0.2     
#>   rmarkdown_1.15  stats_3.6.1     stringi_1.4.3   stringr_1.4.0  
#>   tinytex_0.16    tools_3.6.1     utils_3.6.1     xfun_0.9       
#>   yaml_2.2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You did nothing wrong. RStudio IDE just fails to recognise the chunks after the verbatim code. You just have to live with those side effects.